# ¿Cómo compartir configuración de Qt entre proyectos anidados?

Tags: c++, qt

En `Qt` se pueden crear proyectos anidados, para lo cual hay que definir el proyecto principal como `SUBDIRS`. Aparte de esta configuración, el proyecto principal no admite muchas más modificaciones.

Si se desea compartir, por ejemplo, ficheros de configuración(.pri) entre los diferentes subproyectos se puede optar por varías vías:

- Indicar la ruta absoluta al fichero. La desventaja de este mecanismo es que puede dar problemas al trabajar en grupo, pues obligas a que todo el mundo tenga los proyectos en el mismo sitio.
- Indicar la ruta relativa al fichero. La desventaja de este sistema radica en el hecho de que cada subproyecto puede alojar más subproyectos, lo que obliga a indicar una ruta diferente para cada proyecto.
- Almacenar la ruta en una variable del sistema, lo que obliga a crear, editar y mantener, generalmente a mano, dicha variable del sistema.

Lo ideal sería poder determinar la ruta a partir de la ubicación del proyecto padre y conseguir que dicha información fuese accesible por todos los proyectos. Lo comentado aquí sería extensible a cualquier tipo de valores a compartir entre los diferentes proyectos (información de versión, manifiesto, ...)

¿No existe ningún mecanismo un poco más elegante para compartir información en el contexto de los proyectos anidados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usted usa *Qt5* considere `.qmake.conf` en el proyecto principal en que podría definir las variables como `top_srcdir`:

```
top_srcdir=$$PWD
top_builddir=$$shadowed($$PWD)
```

Si usa *Qt4* tiene que usar `.qmake.cache` autogenerado de `.qmake.cache.in`

Mire más [aquí](https://wiki.qt.io/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir) (en inglés).

Con esta solución podría usar el camino No.1 pero sin saber la ruta exacta del proyecto principal.